# How to write and expose Java web-services on Oracle Fusion Middleware 11g for table insert/batch insert operation

Tags: web-services, soap, jdeveloper

I am using Oracle Fusion Middleware and have to write and expose a web service so that it can be use to insert/batch data into a table from another system. Earlier we were using SQL*Loader to upload the data through flat files.

Comment: what is your code and errors if you get any?

Comment: Please edit your question to add some more useful information like code, context, configurations etc...